# Установка своей темы на WordPress

Tags: wordpress, дизайн

Подскажите, где найти директорию wordpress на ubuntu 16.04. Хочу свою тему поставить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно корневая директория WordPress это /var/www/сайт или /var/www/html/сайт.

Чтобы точно узнать корневую директорию, выберите в административной части Внешний вид - Редактор, найдите файл footer.php и в самый конец, перед закрывающей скобкой ?> (если она есть), или просто в самый конец файла вставьте строку

```
echo ABSPATH;
```

Внимание! Неправильные действия могут привести к неработоспособности сайта.

Если все сделано правильно, на любой странице сайта в самом низу вы увидите путь к корневой папке WordPress, что-то типа /var/www/сайт/

Темы находятся по относительному пути /wp-content/themes/. Туда можно в новую подпапку залить дополнительную тему. Не перезаписывайте и не удаляйте вложенные папки имеющихся тем!

Вот только если вы туда и зальете новую тему, ничего не произойдёт. Надо включить новую тему в админке.

Поэтому более простой путь - в административной части сайта перейти на Внешний вид->темы и там нажать кнопку Добавить тему. Далее выбрать из репозитория или скачать с диска (нужен zip файл с темой).

Comment: А как попасть в директорию var/www/html? Я никак не могу найти ее

Comment: Ну если вы не можете найти директорию в ubuntu, вам, наверное, не следует производить какие-либо манипуляции на сервере. Ставьте тему через стандартный функционал WordPress, как описано в последнем абзаце.

Comment: Я буквально неделю назад перешёл с виндовса.. разбираюсь с новой операционной системой. Мне нужно  натянуть свою вёрстку на вордпресс.